# spring distributed database transaction manager

Tags: database, spring, distributed, transactionmanager

This is quite a common question and yet the answers are unclear to me.  I have 2 different databases on 2 different servers.  One is a pure xml database and the other a traditional dbms (sql server).  Can anybody point me to recent articles or their experience in dealing with transaction management.  I have put together a 1pc strategy which works fine for runtime exceptions.  However, I am not sure if it is bullet-proof.  Secondly, using spring junit test how to specify a default rollback?  It only rolls back the first transactionmanager's transactions.  The other transactions are stored in the other database.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use a ChainedTransactionManager.

Spring has implemented one of these for neo4j, so you can take the code out of the project.

There was a good article on how to do this, but cant find it anymore.  But perhaps this is enough to get you started..

Comment: I came across that in one of the threads.  There are also the JOTM and Atomikos options.  Just not sure if there are limitations for instance, JOTM works with a light-weight server like tomcat, which is what I am using.  Any suggestions?

Comment: sharman atomikos or chained transaction manager?Which one you choose?